# Unexpected browser refresh in Angular 6 simple educational app

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, events, data-binding

Taking a good udemy course in Angular 6.  Lots of property binding and events right now.  I have a primary component that includes 2 children.  One child passes an event back and then property and @Input occur in other component so that parent can notify second child.  I have console.log showing that all components are sending and receiving correctly.  When I run it, my console.log shows correct data for a split second, then refreshes.  My console.log shows:

- recipes onRecipeClicked name: My Recipe (shows parent got data correctly)
- recipeDetail inRecipe name: My Recipe  (shows second child got data)
- Navigated to http://localhost:4200/*  (shows that somehow an unexpected refresh occurs).

For a split second, I can see the proper info on the screen, then back to basics.  If I preLoad a default value in the parent component (so it is there before any interaction or events from first child) ... that works great.  So basic plumbing seems OK.  But if I use the @Output and @Input ... I can see the data flowing correctly, but with no visible error ... I refresh and never see (for more than a split second) the correct data.  I am using Chrome but also tried it in Firefox and got the same behavior.  Thanks,

Comment: Mind sharing your code?

Comment: Escpecially, your router config. It might be some invalid configuration, that triggers the redirect. Also, you can toggle "preserve log" in Chrome dev tools for a console to see all console output after navigation.

Answer (score 1):

We are not using routing at this point but ... it turns out that it was tied to that.  Turns out that I had one incorrect href.  Instead of href="#" ... one of mine was href="*" ... when I fixed that ... problem went away.  I had toggled the preserve log ... but there was nothing in the log about this.  Apparently it just hit it and refreshed.  So, as expected, it was a DFU issue (dumb darn user).  Thanks,